# How to create a post request using C++ and sockets (for a C++ web crawler)?

Tags: c++, html, http, sockets, post

I'm literally trying to create a post requests using just C++ and sockets (for my c++ web crawler) to simulate many kinds of form clicks. I've been trying to figure out what goes in the header and the body of a minimal http post request. What I've tried so far is examine the packets sent from my own browser using wireshark, and I've also examined the html page.

What I know so far is that the body of a post request is encoded.

There are probably easier ways to do this, but I still would like to know what members of stackoverflow know about creating working post requests.

Here's a screenshot of the http post request I'm trying to replicate. I got this request by clicking the upvote button on this post.

[image]

If you look at the screen shot, you can see some cryptic stuff. For example, how can I create this in my own C++ program: "fkey=a883e754083fc33ff1ad63da544602d8"?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you mean. The POST content is determined by the <form> element corresponding to the submit button for an HTML form. Requests can also be generated by Javascript, in which case it may be very non-obvious from looking at the HTML how precisely the request was generated. Perhaps analyzing the same website with a debugging tool like Chrome's inspector or Firebug may help you.

Answer (score 2):

The traditional old-school mechanism of doing an http POST is the html tags:

```
<form action=some-url method=post> ... </form>
```

That would be directly visible on the web page source.  However nowadays http posts may be handled via .js (ex. XMLHttpRequest)
You might not easily see this on the page without tools such as Firebug.

Comment: Why that coma after `action`? `action=some-url,` ???

Comment: @elclanrs a typo.  Thanks for catching.

Comment: Old school? If you are using XHR for everything you need some lessons learned.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably interacting with a page using Javascript. It's a whole different animal to figure out what a page with javascript will do if you just *look* at it.